# How do you test methods that use Angular $http

Tags: angularjs

I have this factory service (I am displaying the TypeScript code because it is easier to read)

```
module cockpit.services {
'use strict';
export class loginService {
        static $inject = ['$http', 'baseUrl'];
    constructor(private $http, private baseUrl: string) {
        console.log(typeof this.$http);
    }
        getUserId(uName: string, pwd: string): number {
        var userId = 0;
        this.$http.put(this.baseUrl + '/login',
            {userName: uName,password: pwd})
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                userId = data.userId;});
        return userId;
    }
}}
```

and I am using the following qUnit test to test it

```
module('serviceTests', {
setup: function() {
    var appMocks = angular.module('appMocks', []);
    appMocks.config(function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$httpBackend',
            angular.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator);
        $provide.constant('baseUrl', '');
    });
    injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'cockpit', 'appMocks']);
    httpBackend = injector.get('$httpBackend');
},
teardown: function() {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
}});
test('loginService', function () {
   var service;
   httpBackend.whenPUT('/login').respond(200,{ userId: 23 });
   service = injector.get('loginService');
   var id = service.getUserId('easy', 'path');
   equal(id, 23, 'returns a userId');
});
```

Everything works beautifully except the test statement itself.  I can step through the code and watch the success callback get executed and the userId in the service gets populated correctly, but the value in the return statement isn't passed back to the id variable in the test and it fails.  So the service is working fine.  I just can't prove it.

I obviously have the test somehow wired up incorrectly, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should be doing is using promises in getUserId. Since it is just returning right away, it will always return 0. Instead you should return a promise, that is resolved with the correct id value once you get it.

[Here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) are the docs for $q.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You have to love it.  The test now passes, but there is no content on my qUnit test page.  The only reason I know the test passes is that there is a check in the title on the tab.